# Changing MSSQLServer service login account (for sql server 2005)

Tags: sql-server-2005

If we change the password on the account that is used to run the MSSQLServer service, and we change the password in the service properties, do we have to restart the service and/or reboot the server.

Ideally we'd like to leave it running until the next scheduled reboot.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to stop and restart the service or reboot the server, but not both (although rebooting the server will stop and restart the service). The service should continue to run without any issues after you change the password until you get the opportunity to reboot or restart.